# Plotting time series data where 1st column is the

Tags: r, time-series

I have data that looks like the image below , the first column ID is the station where the data is read there are 50 different IDs with each reading taken at each station every 5 minutes. what I want to do it use the ID to identify each line plot and the date times ,of course, are the time part.

I have tried this but I get NANs

```
library(data.table)
skdat <- fread('http://dd.weather.gc.ca/hydrometric/csv/SK/hourly/SK_hourly_hydrometric.csv')
skdat1 <-w1 <- read.csv(file="http://dd.weather.gc.ca/hydrometric/csv/SK/hourly/SK_hourly_hydrometric.csv",sep=",",head=TRUE)
head(skdat)
names(skdat)
skdattimeseries <- ts(skdat)
```

any suggestions

[image]

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, along with the algorithm you want to use to perform your task, what you've tried so far and what the expected result should look like.

Comment: Roman I did that???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're really trying to achieve. I got that you want to produce the time series plot of the water level. So, here is my code:

```
file = "http://dd.weather.gc.ca/hydrometric/csv/SK/hourly/SK_hourly_hydrometric.csv"
skdat <- read.csv(file, head=T, sep=",", dec=".")
colnames(skdat) <- c("ID", "Date", "Water.Level", "Grade.1", "Symbol.1", 
            "QA/QC-1", "Discharge/Debit", "Grade.2", "Symbol.2", 
            "QA/QC-2")

#There are 151 Factors of ID
str(skdat$ID)
 #Factor w/ 151 levels "05AH050","05EF001",..: 151 151 151 151 151 151 151 151 151 151 ...

#Create Time Series Plot, this is just for one ID
plot.ts(subset(skdat, as.numeric(ID) %in% 1)$Water.Level, 
    main="Plot TS of ID = 05AH050")
```

Comment: Hey thanks Rendy  that is great!  i am having problems figuring out what is going on with the line   Factor w/ 151 levels "05AH050","05EF001",..: 151 151 151 151 151 151 151 151 151 151 ...   i am thinking i need to list all 151 IDs but what is the 151 151 about? googled Factor w/ but couldnt figure it out?

Comment: that line wasn't a code, that was the output of str(skdat)

Comment: I see the plot show just the index value of the reading what I would like is to have the date time ...is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You should check on how to manipulating plot in R

Comment: > plot.ts(subset(skdat, as.numeric(ID) %in% 1)$Water.Level, main="Plot TS of ID = 05AH050")
> axis(1, skdat$Date, format(skdat$Date, "%b %d"), cex.axis = .7)
Error in axis(1, skdat$Date, format(skdat$Date, "%b %d"), cex.axis = 0.7) : 
  no locations are finite

Comment: OK ill proceed investigating

Comment: open up a new question abt that